# How to select most frequent item id per customer?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the most frequently purchased item (represented by `item_id`) for each customer id (`customer_id`).

```
select distinct on customer_id, most_freq_item from (
select customer_id, item_id as most_freq_item, count(*) as _count
from my_table
group by customer_id, item_id)
order by customer_id, _count desc;
```

This resulted in the error:

> "syntax error at or near "customer _id" after "select distinct on".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select ci.*
from (select customer_id, item_id as most_freq_item,
             count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from my_table
      group by customer_id, item_id
     ) ci
where seqnum = 1;
```

In the event of ties, this returns an arbitrary most frequent value.  If you want all of them, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT stat.*
  FROM (SELECT customer_id, 
               item_id                                      most_freq_item,
               COUNT(*)                                     cnt,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
                                  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)   seqnum
         FROM my_table
        GROUP BY customer_id,
               item_id) stat
 WHERE seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Hello! This answer seems to be going in the right direction but does not get there. If the user wants to get the single most frequent item, then he needs to process the data your query returns to find which item has the higher Cnt value.

Comment: Hi. You're right. By mistake I haven't read the "Most Frequent" part of the title.